# How can I log docker-java operations to the console?

Tags: java, docker, docker-java

I'm using the [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) library in a command-line project, doing things like this:

```
    private DockerClient client;

    public Docker() {
        var config = DefaultDockerClientConfig
            .createDefaultConfigBuilder()
            .withDockerHost("tcp://localhost:2375")
            .build();
        client = DockerClientBuilder
            .getInstance(config)
            .build();
    }

    public String build(String name, Path dockerFilePath) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Building image from: " + dockerFilePath.toString());
        var tags = new HashSet<String>();
        tags.add(name);
        return client
            .buildImageCmd()
            .withNoCache(true)
            .withDockerfile(dockerFilePath.toFile())
            .withTags(tags)
            .start()
            .awaitCompletion()
            .awaitImageId();
    }
```

When I run the `build` method, my app hangs.  I'd troubleshoot that myself, but I can't see what's happening; there's no output in the console.

Hence my question:

**Is there a way I can configure this library so that the Docker output logs to the Windows console?**

Comment: Used a debugger yet?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Nope.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen But I can get this information if I run Docker from the command line, so I feel like there must be a way to get it using the library.  (Unfortunately, the library is _very_ sparsely documented.)

Comment: In times like this, the only thing you can do is dig through source code and see how it's implemented. (grinning-face-with-sweat-emoji)

Comment: @RyanLundy Then get the corresponding source for the module and have a look inside.  You are fortunate, Java supports debugging out of the box if started with the right parameters.